# Django - user rate profile

Tags: python, django, user-profile

I am a newbie to Django and this question might be an easy one, but it has already been bothering me for a while.

```
<form method="post" action="/vote/" class="vote_form">
   <input type="hidden" id="id_link" name="user_profile" class="hidden_id" value="5" />
   <input type="hidden" id="id_voter" name="voter" class="hidden_id" value="3" />
    New Score: <input name="score" class="" value="7" />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^vote/$', auth(VoteFormView.as_view()), name="vote"),
```

views.py

```
class VoteFormView(FormView):
    form_class = VoteForm

    def create_response(self, vdict=dict(), valid_form=True):
        response = HttpResponse(json.dumps(vdict))
        response.status = 200 if valid_form else 500
        return response

    def form_valid(self, form):
        profile = get_object_or_404(UserProfile, pk=form.data['user_profile'])
        user = self.request.user
        score = form.cleaned_data['score']

        prev_votes = Vote.objects.filter(voter=user, profile=profile)
        has_voted = (len(prev_votes) > 0)

        ret = {"success": 1, "profile": profile, "voter: ": user}
        if not has_voted:
            # add vote
            v = Vote.objects.create(voter=user, profile=profile, score=score)
            ret["voteobj"] = v.id
            # else response already ranked  
        return self.create_response(ret, True)


    def form_invalid(self, form):
        ...do something when form invalid...
```

forms.py

```
class VoteForm(forms.ModelForm):
   class Meta:
     model = Vote
```

models.py

```
class Vote(models.Model):
    voter = models.ForeignKey(User)
    profile = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)
    score = models.FloatField(default=10.0)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s voted %s" % (self.voter.username, self.profile)

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, unique=True)
    # Extra attributes
```

As you can see, I have a simple form with 2 fields: a user_profile (PK of a user profile) and a score. After the form is submitted, it has this error: `"form_errors": {"profile": ["This field is required."]}` . So it always goes to to `form_invalid`. 
Where am I supposed to get profile object if it is not form_valid? 
I tried to redefine VoteForm as below, which does not work either.

```
class VoteForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def clean_profile(self):
        profile_pk = self.cleaned_data['profile']
        profile = None
        try:
            profile = UserProfile.objects.get(pk=profile_pk)
        except UserProfile.DoesNotExist:
            raise forms.ValidationError("User profile doesn't exist.")
        return profile

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        vote = super(VoteForm, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        return vote

    class Meta:
        model = Vote
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change your hidden input name from user_profile to profile.

Keep in mind this is a poor design since anyone can inject an arbitrary voter id.

Here is how I would do it

```
class VoteForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = kwargs.pop("user")
        super(VoteForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):

        # manipulate self.user
```

and then in your view

```
form = VoteForm(..., user=request.user)
```

Comment: Thanks! I have changed `user_profile` to `profile` and now profile is ok. I have also removed the voter hidden field from the form. But it complains `user` is not found. Where to put form = `VoteForm(user=request.user)` Is the save method below ok? 
`def save(self, *args, **kwargs):`
`        vote = super(VoteForm, self).save(commit=False)`
`        vote.voter = self.user`
`        vote.save()`
        return vote

Answer (score 0):

The name of your hidden field is `user_profile`, but your code refers to it as just `profile`. Try changing the html of the form so it is named `profile`.

As an aside you should include the voter id in your form, that should be added in your processing code based on the logged in user. Currently anyone could change the voter hidden field and record a vote for a different user.